# Simple way to position a text anywhere on a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, positioning, text, coordinates, text-manipulation

This might be a very easy question but somehow I have failed to find a good answer for.

I wish to put a text, e.g., word/math/string, etc. on a specific location on a Beamer frame. This is probably the simplest thing you can do with power point.

Currently, the way that I do this is through a massive amount of \center, \hspace, \vspace, etc. which is extremely messy. There is also another way that I used which is inserting them using Tikz, but for some reason whenever I change one coordinate, the other also move.

Ideally, you know every coordinate on the frame, and simply call some function `put(x,y){"word"}`, and the word will start at the (x,y) coordinate.

Is there some simple way achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same trick as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989 to define a coordinate system which coincides with the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

% trick taken from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1989
\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,use page relative coordinates]
  
  % showing a couple of example coordinates
  \node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {(0,0)};
  \node[anchor=south east] at (1,0) {(1,0)};
  \node[anchor=north west] at (0,1) {(0,1)};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (1,1) {(1,1)};

   \node at (0.7,0.3) {test}; 
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tikzpagenodes` to install a coordinate system in which `(0,0)` and `(1,1)` are the bottom left and top right of the text area of the frame, respectively. One could define a command `\put` for that, but I do not see how that syntax is simpler than `(x,y) node {<text>}`, the more so since the latter is more flexible as it easily allows you to add pgf keys.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{frameoverlay/.style={overlay,remember picture,shift={(current page text area.south west)},
x={($(current page text area.south east)-(current page text area.south west)$)},
y={($(current page text area.north west)-(current page text area.south west)$)},nodes={anchor=south west}}}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{TikZ pagenodes}
\begin{tikzpicture}[frameoverlay]
   \path
    (0.5,0.5) node{Hello}
    (0.7,0.7) node{World}
    (0.2,0.1) node{Something}
    (0.6,0.3) node{New};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]